# Помогите с ассемблером

Tags: ассемблер, x86

Изучаю книгу Джона Эриксона "Хакинг искусство эксплойта". Автор дисассемблировал подобный код на СИ:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int i;
    for ( i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        puts("Hello, world!\n" );
    }
}
```

Я работаю через PowerShell, ввел такие команды (mingw):

```
>gcc -g main.c
>gdb -q ./a.exe
>set disassembly intel
>disassemble main
(плюс брейк на main())
```

В итоге у меня ассемблерный код такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У автора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меня особенно волнует команда mov. Я слышал что добавляется значение обычно к указателю ebp, плюс у автора это не 1с, а -4. Возможно ли это из-за того что я сижу на винд 7,  а автор на линуксе. И чем могут вызваны отличия.

Comment: И извиняюсь если неправильно оформил, первый вопрос, обещаюсь исправиться.

Comment: Разные компиляторы Си (разные версии одного и того же компилятора) с разными настройками оптимизации могут дать разный ассемблерный код, работающий при этом одинаково. В качестве регистра базы для адресации в стеке может использоваться как esp, так и ebp или ebx (да и в принципе почти любой регистр). Ошибки или проблемы тут никакой нет.

Comment: Хорошо, а если не трудно, Вы б не могли описать как работает участок кода до mov в первом случае. Описание автора сводится к тому, что мы отнимает от ebp 4 байта, чтобы хранить int, а в моем случае это делается видно как-то по-другому.

Comment: Почитайте про стековый фрейм (он же стековый кадр). Это довольно большая тема, не вижу смысла все это переписывать своими словами. Смысл в том, что обычно для адресации внутри фрейма в стеке для удобства используется регистр ebp, но компилятор может извратиться и использовать просто указатель стека для адресации.

Comment: Адресация через esp и ebp аналогична, просто у вас и в примере в книге значения esp и ebp различаются примерно на 20h (esp = ebp - 20h), поэтому у вас прибавляется число к esp, а в книге вычитается от ebp.

Comment: Да, спасибо что помогли разобраться . Я только сейчас понял, что он по сути дает те же -4, просто изначально отнимает 32, а потом добавляет 28.

Comment: Да, примерно так.

Comment: @dudavik, вам может пригодятся вот этот сайт: https://godbolt.org.

Comment: @eanmos, благодарю, да, я думаю будет полезен.

Comment: Если в коде `EBP+4` (8,12,16) - это обращение к аргументам функции, а если `EBP-4` (8,12,16 и тд.) - это обращение к локальным переменным.